# Identify that unit tests are running during runtime

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing

I have a situation where I want my system to load a different configuration while running unit tests (in order to keep unit tests small and efficient).

I'm currently using maven and its surefire plugin in order to run unit tests. Is there a way to achieve this? The only idea that comes to my mind is setting an environment variable in the surefire plugin configuration, but I am also open to other possibilities.

Comment: What do you mean by "my system to load a different configuration"?  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Do you use test suites ?

Comment: To give a concrete example: On production and Integration tests I use Zookeeper to hold system configuration, but I do not want to have to load a Zookeeper instance for each unit test, and therefore for unit tests I would read the same configuration from file.

Comment: Not sure how zookeeper ties up in your project but can't you mock zookeeper. Especially when it comes to retrieving configuration.

Comment: Is this not something that could be addressed in the unit test code itself? e.g. in `JUnit`'s `@Before`? You could manually build the system configuration there, possibly from a test file under `src/test/resources`

Answer (score 0):

By default Maven uses a different configuration for unit tests. You just have to store it in `src/test/resources`